# Python 3.4 pip install

Tags: python, macos, xlrd

I am trying to install the `xlrd` module on my Mac, however when I open `IDLE` and import the `xlrd` module, I get the error:

```
Input Error: No module named xlrd
```

To install it, I used in my home directory...

```
sudo pip install xlrd
```

... and it is installed successfully.

Note that I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4.0 on my computer, in case this is what is causing problems. I want it installed for Python 3.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To avoid conflicts between parallel Python 2 and Python 3
>   installations, only the versioned pip3 and pip3.4 commands are
>   bootstrapped by default

You can try `sudo pip3 install xlrd` or `sudo pip3.4 install xlrd` to use the Python 3.4, see docs here https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#bootstrapping-pip-by-default