# Python can't find Django

Tags: python, django, macos, shell, terminal

I installed Django with the following command in the OSX terminal:

```
sudo pip install django
```

but when I check whether python3.4 can find it using the command:

```
import django
```

I get an error saying it can't find it. However if I use the default Python2.7 that comes with OSX and type:

```
import django
```

Then I don't receive any problems. How do I make it so python3.4 sees the location of Django? Is adding the address of where django is a better choice(how do I do this?) or should I had tried to install Django somewhere else instead? If so where and again how do I do specify the location through the command?

Basically I want to know:

1. What is the command in the terminal to make it so python3.4 can find django.
2. Is it better to make it so python3.4 knows the location of django, wherever it is (default python2.7 location I guess?) or to install django elsewhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256510/python-3-4-pip-install/28256854#28256854

Comment: If you allow me a suggestion, virtualenv is very handy to create separate environment for different projects: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/12.0.7 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to install django for python3, you should do:

pip3 install django

If you want to install django for python2, you should do:

pip install django.

You can not use library installed with pip to works on python3 because python3 and python2 have their own set of environment and path library

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not

```
import Django
```

It's,

```
import django
```

Also, make sure you're using the correct version of pip.  You'll probably need to specify pip3 or pip-3.2 (one of the two, can't remember how OSX does it off the top of my head), since python 3 is not the default Python version, unless you're using virtualenv.

Comment: What does the version of pip have to do with the question? The django tutorial said it had to be up to date or python would give an error but i mean it did install with no error so i assume that part is okay. Also you didnt really answer the question. Maybe my question was vague so i added more information on what i was asking.

Comment: Except I did.  My answer is the same as the accepted answer, I said you needed to use pip3, not pip, yet you downvoted me.

Comment: First off i cant downvote since my rep is below 125. Secondly your answer was just that, an answer with little to no information. For future reference if someone asks a question give an explenation not just an answer.